# error: ‘TCP_NODELAY’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: compiling, tcp, error-handling, delay

I am trying to compile ChatScipt v7.55 in Ubuntu 16.04. But when I use `make server` command, I get this error:

```
evserver.cpp: In function ‘int settcpnodelay(int)’:
evserver.cpp:263:40: error: ‘TCP_NODELAY’ was not declared in this scope
     return setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (void*) &on, sizeof(on));
                                        ^
Makefile:110: recipe for target 'evserver.o' failed
make: *** [evserver.o] Error 1
```

This is the full result of the command:

```
************ LINUX VERSION ************
g++ -c  -std=c++11 -Wall  -funsigned-char  -Wno-write-strings -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-strict-aliasing  -DLOCKUSERFILE=1  -DEVSERVER=1 -DEVSERVER_FORK=1  -DDISCARDPOSTGRES=1 -DDISCARDMONGO=1 -DDISCARDMYSQL=1  -Ievserver evserver.cpp -o evserver.o
evserver.cpp: In function ‘int settcpnodelay(int)’:
evserver.cpp:263:40: error: ‘TCP_NODELAY’ was not declared in this scope
     return setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (void*) &on, sizeof(on));
                                        ^
Makefile:110: recipe for target 'evserver.o' failed
make: *** [evserver.o] Error 1
```

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding  `#include <netinet/tcp.h>`  in above of ” evserver.cpp ” file