# Compile ChatScript

Tags: compiling

I want to use CS externally in my program. I tried to uncomment `// #define NOMAIN 1` within `common.h` file as the tutorial says here:

> Embedding Step #1 First, you will need to modify `common.h and compile
>   the system. You need to add all the CS .cpp files to your build list.
>   Find the // #define NOMAIN 1 and uncomment it. This will allow you to
>   compile your program as the main program and ChatScript merely as a
>   collection of routines to accompany it.

But I can't understand what does it mean by

> add all the CS .cpp files to your build list

May someone explains this for me?

After uncommenting `// #define NOMAIN 1` I tried to run `make server`command to compile, But I got this error message:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:107: recipe for target 'binary' failed
make: *** [binary] Error 1
```

You can see the full result here: https://github.com/bwilcox-1234/ChatScript/issues/171

Comment: Similar, but no answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/396726/117549

Comment: Post an issue to GitHub.